# Help with TDA2030A Amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio, circuit-design, debugging, proteus

I am designing an amplifier circuit using TDA2030A, but now I am stuck in providing power to the circuit. As mentioned in the datasheet, I copied single power supply circuit for my amp. But the simulation in proteus is showing an error if I just test the same single power supply circuit from the Datasheet, but if, I provide it a negative supply (split power mode), the simulation works.

[image: with dual power supply]

Circuit similar to that in the datasheet for a single power supply. (Not working)
[image: single power supply]

These are the two circuits from the datasheet. (I want single power supply)
[image: Datasheet cicuit]

I want to drive a 5W speaker, please tell me what I am doing wrong in the circuit.
secondly, is it good idea to transfer the second circuit (Proteus simulation) to the breadboard and check it.

If possible please tell me how can I provide a split power supply to it using only one 12V 2Amp adapter.

**Thankyou**

Comment: Regarding your other question: "secondly, is it good idea to transfer the second circuit (Proteus simulation) to the breadboard and check it" I am not sure if you are asking as a beginner. If so, then yes, you can, even if you are concerned with damaging the TDA. Start with a low supply voltage (9V..12V) and a high ohm (e.g. 100..1K) load. Check your DC, at the +input, the input swing and the output swing (sinus with no distortion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at (and compare) the DC voltage at the + input of TDA2030.

You made a mistake in connecting the output of RV1 to the net between R6 and R7. Compare your schematic to those from the datasheet!

[image]

I would connect the output of RV1 **only** to C2. RV1 now pulls the DC voltage at the + input to around 0 V, then the TDA2030 can only work if it has a negative supply that is at a lower voltage than 0 V.

In case of a single supply solution the DC voltage at the + input needs to be about 6 V DC.

Do a DC operating point simulation and check the DC voltages of the TDA2030's inputs for both circuits.

Comment: Woohoo!!! Thankyou so much. I tried it and it worked. I didn't even realize that silly mistake.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I want to ask you how can I provide a split power supply to the circuit using 12V 2Amp Adapter. Or suggest any other method to power??

Comment: The most common way to "split a supply" is to create a "virtual ground" by means of an opamp based circuit. Here's one: https://www.eleccircuit.com/power-supply-splitter-circuit-using-op-amp/  But you don't need that, the TDA2030 supports a single supply. Also for an audio power amplifier that needs a symmetrical supply it is better to use a real symmetrical supply, for example: http://powersupply33.com/simple-symmetrical-power-supply-25v-25v.html

Comment: Look at the volume control that was shorting the bias voltage. It is 10 ohms!